# При нажатии на кнопку "Задать вопрос" в поле редактирования находится текст уже опубликованного вопроса

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано

На сайте `http://ru.stackoverflow.com/` при нажатии на кнопку "Задать вопрос" открывает не окно для формирования нового вопроса, а окно с редактированием старого (последнего) вопроса.
На `http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/` такого поведения не наблюдается.
На `http://stackoverflow.com/` вопросов не задавал, проверить не могу.

Браузер: Chrome (Версия 52.0.2743.82 m)

Comment: Если старый вопрос был не задан, а сохранен как черновик, то при нажатии "Задать вопрос" открывается именно тот последний черновик. На Мете так же как и на основном сайте в этом плане поведение. Главное дождаться появления надписи "черновик сохранен" под телом вопроса.

Comment: @alexolut вопрос задан и отвечен

Comment: Есть ещё вариант, что страница была открыта в нескольких вкладках одновременно. Там где не был задан, сохранился как черновик. Его и показывает теперь.

Comment: @alexolut вероятно, это и было причиной. нажал "отменить", всплывающее окно спросило про сохранение изменений. судя по всему, это и был дублированный черновик. после подтверждения он закрылся. теперь всё ок.

Comment: [Об эффективных багрепортах](http://egorfine.com/ru/articles/effective-bugreports/) =)